# galaxy tab 2 usb issues

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, usb, connection-issues, samsung-kies, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-7

My new Galaxy Tab 2 can't connect to my PC via USB. When I plug it in my PC, it plays a tone. It means some new hardware has been connected. It appears in Kies as GT-P3113. But when I mouse-over it, it says connecting... But it has completed the connection only 3 times (more or less). The rest of the time, it doesn't work. It also doesn't show up in my computer as an external storage, so I can't add files that way either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please check my question [**`Unable to connect Samsung Galaxy (Tab-2) GT-P3100 to Computer via USB`**](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/50603/31054) and its [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/50619/31054) too.

It is defiantly helpful to you...